# IllegalArgumentException when executing command with ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder, illegalargumentexception

I'm writing a simple Java Application where user can execute cmd commands. There is just a TextField to enter the command and a button to execute it. The code looks as follows:

```
sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", message.getText());
                    Process pr = pb.start();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine if the user executes

> notepad.exe

But for some reason I get the **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException** if the command is for example:

> "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   www.youtube.com

It's probably because of the quotes, does anybody know a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you run it without the quotes? The `IllegalArgumentException` basically means *Command not found*.

Comment: I can run it without the quotes. But ideally the Application should be able to run all of the commands that can be run in the cmd itself.

Comment: No, the Exceprion is coming from the `Process pr = pb.start();`

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` expects list of arguments passed as `List<String>` or `String...`. Your problem is that you are passing two separate arguments as one because they have space not in quotes. So you need to split user command on spaces that are not placed in quotes. To do this you can use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+");
//pattern will find strings between quotes or separate words
Matcher m = p.matcher(userCmd);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("adding " + m.group());//just for debugging 
    list.add(m.group());
}
```

like in this example

```
String userCmd="\"C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\""
        +" www.youtube.com";

List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add("cmd.exe");
list.add("/c");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(userCmd);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("adding " + m.group());
    list.add(m.group());
}

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
Process pr = pb.start();

InputStream err=pr.getErrorStream();
BufferedReader errReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(err));
String line=null;
while((line=errReader.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

which in my case prints only error about not finding such path on my computer, but in user computer should work fine.

Comment: Does it work with a program you do have? I'm not sure it will work with the quotes as the `ProcessBuilder` escapes the path so the quotes would be passed as literals.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes if I change path to real one it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you asked for a workaround, you could try trimming the quotes from the whole string before the builder runs it: `message.getText().replaceAll("\"", "");`.

The downside is that you can have more complex cases where it's hard to figure out what to trim or not.

Comment: Surely this won't work if the quotes are there for a reason. This isn't a workable solution.

Comment: I agree. Workarounds are by definition *not viable solutions*.